# Cannot apply text-align to Material UI Input Component, but everything else works

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

When I inspect, it seems like all the input styles I've created actually go to the outside div Material UI creates that wraps the Input.  But the other styles work so I'm not sure what's going on?

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  formControl: {
    ...
  },
  label: {
    ...
  },
  input: {
    color: "black",
    '&:after': {
      borderColor: 'black',
      textAlign: 'center'
    },
    fontSize: getFontSize(),
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center'  // this is the only thing that does NOT work
  },
  inputElement: {
    textAlign : 'center'
  }
}));

const classes = useStyles();

<FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
  {
    labelText &&
    <InputLabel
      className={classes.label}
      htmlFor="component-helper"
    >
      {labelText}
    </InputLabel>
  }
  <Input
    className={classes.input}
    classes={classes.inputElement}  // this does NOT work either
    id={"component-helper"}
    value={text}
    onBlur={handleBlur}
    onChange={handleChange}
    aria-describedby="component-helper-text"
  />
</FormControl>
```

Comment: In case of material-ui <input> element 'className' is for the wrapper element. As is stated in the documents. So that is correct behaviour. Also the document says that 'classes' props is to override or extend the styles applied to the component. can you try any other css property than textAlign. Just for try

Comment: can you create stackblitz to replicate similar issue to debug easily

Comment: @NagaSaiA okay let me see what i can do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue with the following code in your question:

```
  <Input
    className={classes.input}
    classes={classes.inputElement}  // this does NOT work either
    id={"component-helper"}
    value={text}
    onBlur={handleBlur}
    onChange={handleChange}
    aria-describedby="component-helper-text"
  />
```

is that the `classes` property should look like in the following:

```
  <Input
    className={classes.input}
    classes={{input: classes.inputElement}}
    id={"component-helper"}
    value={text}
    onBlur={handleBlur}
    onChange={handleChange}
    aria-describedby="component-helper-text"
  />
```

Below is a working example. I've used

```
classes={inputClasses}
```

in my example, but this is equivalent to

```
classes={{root: inputClasses.root, input: inputClasses.input}}
```

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { makeStyles, FormControl, InputLabel, Input } from "@material-ui/core";

const useInputStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    color: "black",
    "&:after": {
      borderColor: "black"
    },
    fontSize: 12
  },
  input: {
    textAlign: "center"
  }
}));

function App() {
  const inputClasses = useInputStyles();
  const labelText = "Test Label";
  return (
    <FormControl>
      <InputLabel htmlFor="component-helper">{labelText}</InputLabel>
      <Input
        classes={inputClasses}
        id="component-helper"
        aria-describedby="component-helper-text"
      />
    </FormControl>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit Input classes]

Comment: thank you for explaining as well.  answers are great, but explanations are better.

Answer (score 0):

In case of material-ui  element 'className' is for the wrapper element. As is stated in the documents. So that is correct behaviour. Also the document says that 'classes' props is to override or extend the styles applied to the component. Do the following -

```
classes={{input: classes.input}}
```

Comment: I've done something similar already in the OP but i changed it to look a bit similar to what you suggested, but it's still not working unfortunately.

Comment: I suggested exactly the same what @Ryan did. But yes I agree that his explanation is good. :-)

Comment: You correctly demonstrated the syntax for the `classes` property, however the `input` style rule in the question contained incorrect CSS (`alignItems` instead of `textAlign`) which is probably why it didn't work when @user1189352 tried it. If you had specified `classes={{input: classes.inputElement}}` it likely would have worked for @user1189352. Whenever possible I try to include a working example. It proves to myself that the solution works and it removes ambiguity about how the solution should be applied.